# Integration of a piecewise function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, piecewise

Define

```
f[x_, i_] := Piecewise[{{1/n, 
0 < x < (i - 1)/n}, {(i/n - x), (i - 1)/n < x < i/n} , {0, 
i/n < x}} ];
```

I would like to compute

```
Integrate[f[x,i]*f[y,i]*f[x,j]*f[y,j],{x,0,1},{y,0,1}],
```

assuming that $n$, $i$ and $j$ are natural numbers and $1\leq j\leq i\leq n$. So far, I have try to use `PiecewiseExpand[f[x,i]*f[y,i]*f[x,j]*f[y,j]]` and split the integral in different ways. However, it takes forever the computation of the double integral. Do you have any advice to proceed?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Your problem is that you define a function of just $x$ and $i$ that somehow depends upon $n$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork shouldn't it just treat the `n` as constant and go about the integration as in `Integrate[Piecewise[{{ x, 0 <= x < a}, {a, x >= a}}],x]`?

Comment: Which I now notice returns an incorrect result.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I tried defining instead `f[x_, i_,n_] := Piecewise[{{1/n, 
0 < x < (i - 1)/n}, {(i/n - x), (i - 1)/n < x < i/n} , {0, 
i/n < x}} ];` but it did not shown any improvement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is:

```
res[j_, j_, n_] := (3 j - 2)^2 /(9 n^6)  /; j <= n
res[j_, i_, n_] := (2 j - 1)^2 /(4 n^6)  /; j <= i <= n
```

Testing against your function:

```
rr[j1_, i1_, n1_] := Block[{j = j1, i = i1, n = n1}, 
                      Integrate[f[x, i]*f[y, i]*f[x, j]*f[y, j], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]]

list = Sort /@ RandomInteger[{1, 10^2}, {100, 3}];
rr @@@ list == res @@@ list
(* True *)
```

But please **don't ask me** how I came to know it :)

`ArrayPlot[ ]` for `n == 4`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you! This actually solves the question as I formulated it. The true is that I also would like to compute `Integrate[f[w,i]*f[x,i]*f[x,j]*f[y,j]*f[y,k]*f[w,k],{w,0,1},{x,0,1},{y,0,1}]`, and so on. But I am afraid I should do some math on paper and latter ask mathematica.