# Getting error message when integrating a simple piecewise function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, piecewise

I reviewed the following questions:
[question 1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98480/integration-of-a-piecewise-function) and [question 2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120172/integrate-over-a-piecewise-function), but I need to the following integral of a piecewise function:

```
A[1][t_] = Piecewise[{{1 - 2*t, 0 <= t <= 1/2}}, 0]
Integrate[A[1][x], {x, 0, t}]
```

I want the following output

```
Piecewise[{{t - t^2, 0 <= t <= 1/2}}, 0]
```

but I get the error

> Integrate::pwrl: Unable to prove that integration limits {0,t} are real. Adding assumptions may help.

Also, for

```
A2[t_] = Piecewise[{{2*t, 0 <= t <= 1/2}, {2 - 2*t, 1/2 <= t <= 1}}, 0]
```

I need the following output:

[image: Integrate Piecewise]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your expected output for the second case seems to be wrong. You should get `1/2` for `t=1`

Comment: (1) You shouldn't expand questions after people have answered, unless you weren't clear enough to begin with. (2) Your second question doesn't make sense. Guessing you might mean you want the integral of `A2`, then the needed output is wrong.

Comment: @Michael E2  I need to Integral of  all  functions in pieceswise, separately, without consider distance.

Comment: But the way the integral is defined in calculus, and in *Mathematica*, the result should be continuous, which your desired output is not. This will output what you want: `MapAt[Integrate[#, t] &, A2[t], {1, All, 1}]`.

Comment: @Michael E2 Many many thanks. Your comment is my answer. If possible for you change comment to answer, and reply about :  `{1, All, 1}`.

Comment: You're welcome. The `{1, All, 1}` is the `Part` of the expression. It's  a lot to explain, but you might start with the tutorials in http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ExpressionsOverview.html, especially the last four. Examining `TreeForm[A2[t]]` might help. You also could look up `MapAt` in the docs & its examples.

Comment: As for answering, I think you have two good answers to your initial question, and as I hinted, the site's policy discourages changing the question too much; see http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1614. I think the Q&A has a nice coherence presently and mixing in my answer would confuse things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

```
ClearAll[x, t]
A0[t_] := Piecewise[{ {1 - 2*t, 0 <= t <= 1/2}}];
Assuming[t > 0, Integrate[A0[x], {x, 0, t}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I edited my question. Please review if possible.

Comment: @user45459 I would add that Nasser is only following the advice in the error message. (Literally, it was suggesting `Integrate[A[1][x], {x, 0, t}, Assumptions -> t \[Element] Reals]`, or rather `Integrate[A[1][x], {x, 0, t}, Assumptions -> {0, t} \[Element] Reals]`.)

Answer (score 4):

Ok it may be strange to put an assumption on t but this

```
A[1][t_] = Piecewise[{{1 - 2*t, 0 <= t <= 1/2}}, 0]
Assuming[0 <= t <= 1, Integrate[A[1][x], {x, 0, t}]]
```

works

Comment: I edited my question. Please review if possible.

Comment: even `Assuming[Element[t, Reals], ..]` works (including the 0 for t<0 part)

Answer (score 2):

There's also

```
A[1][t_] = Piecewise[{{1 - 2*t, 0 <= t <= 1/2}}, 0];
FullSimplify @ Normal @ Integrate[Simplify`PWToUnitStep @ A[1][x], {x, 0, t}]
```

[image]

Advantage: no `Assumptions/Assuming`.